# SignalR in Asp.net MVC 3: hub is undefined

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I'm a newbie in SignalR. I'm trying to do this [Progress Bar example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh852586.aspx).
I can't download and install the packages via NuGet, cause there is a proxy in my work that denies the access. So I include de DLLs and the scripts in project by myself.

My view code is below:

```
<h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
<input type="button" id="bookButton" value="Book flight" />
<br />
<b>Status:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span id="msg"></span>
<hr />
<input type="button" id="percButton" value="Process pending emails" />
<div id="bar" style="border: #000 1px solid; width: 300px;">
</div>
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/gauge-bar.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/json2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.signalr.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/signalr/hubs")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/simple-gauge-bar.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var bookingHub = $.connection.bookingHub;
        $("#percButton").click(function () {
            bookingHub.processPendingEmails();
        });

        $("#bookButton").click(function () {
            bookingHub.bookFlight("fco", "jfk");
        });

        bookinghub.updategaugebar = function (perc) {
            $("#bar").html(gaugebar.generate(perc));
        };
        bookinghub.displaymessage = function (message) {
            $("#msg").html(message);
        };

        $.connection.hub.start();
    });
</script>
```

My Hub code:

```
 public class BookingHub : Hub
{
    public void Send(String message)
    {

        // Call the addMessage method on all clients.
        Clients.displayMessage(message);
    }

    public void BookFlight(String from, String to)
    {
        // Book first leg
        Clients.displayMessage(String.Format("Booking flight: {0}-{1} ...", from, to));
        Thread.Sleep(2000);

        // Book return 
        Clients.displayMessage(String.Format("Booking flight: {0}-{1} ...", to, from));
        Thread.Sleep(3000);

        // Book return 
        Clients.displayMessage(String.Format("Booking flight: {0}-{1} ...", to, from));
        Thread.Sleep(2000);

        // Some return value
        Clients.displayMessage("Flight booked successfully.");
    }

    public void ProcessPendingEmails()
    {
        Clients.updateGaugeBar(10);
        Thread.Sleep(2000);

        Clients.updateGaugeBar(40);
        Thread.Sleep(3000);

        Clients.updateGaugeBar(64);
        Thread.Sleep(2000);

        Clients.updateGaugeBar(77);
        Thread.Sleep(2000);

        Clients.updateGaugeBar(92);
        Thread.Sleep(3000);

        Clients.updateGaugeBar(99);
        Thread.Sleep(2000);

        Clients.updateGaugeBar(100);
    }
}
```

When I ran the project, I noticed the bookingHub is undefined, and I've got null reference errors at this point.

What Am I doing wrong to get this error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you get when you access /signalr/hubs in your browser?

Comment: check the source code of the page, and see if all the libraries are being loaded. I once had the same problem because i needed to re-map the hub routes again in global.asax (if you're injecting to signalr that may be the problem)

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing the attribute,

```
[HubName("bookingHub")]
```

on your BookingHub class? e.g.

```
 [HubName("bookingHub")]
 public class BookingHub : Hub
{
    public void Send(String message)
    {

        // Call the addMessage method on all clients.
        Clients.displayMessage(message);
    }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Global.asax to your web app and add this to global.ajax.cs:

```
namespace SampleWebApplication
{
    public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();
        }
    }
}
```

See https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/QuickStart-Hubs